# Is there a way I can register user defined functions with standard java objects

Tags: java, selenium

is there a way I can register user defined functions with standard java objects

to explain better, I have a simple selenium code.

```
    ObectRepository OR = PageFactory.initElements(objDriver, ObectRepository.class);        
    OR.objLinkRegister.click();
    OR.objInputFirstName.sendKeys(strTestmap.get("ABC")); //objInputFirstName is an input box
```

Now instead of using sendkeys function for the input field, I would want use a function which will do the sendkeys functionality as well as, could do my own stuff. The code could look like below...

```
    ObectRepository OR = PageFactory.initElements(objDriver, ObectRepository.class);        
    OR.objLinkRegister.click();
    OR.objInputFirstName.sendKeysWithReports(strTestmap.get("ABC"));
    // normal flow below.

   private class myClass()
   {
    public void sendKeysWithReports(objInputFirstName)
    {
        objInputFirstName.SendKeys;
        //Do some stuff return to the notrmal flow
    }
   }
```

Please ignore any syntactical errors as I am a newbie to Java :)

Answer (score 1):

You already got to the right path by trying to create a subclass, which proxies method calls to the internal element. In your case, it would be:

```
public class ReportingObjectRepository {
    private ObjectRepository internal;

    public ReportingObjectRepository(ObjectRepository internal) {
        this.internal = internal;
    }

    public void sendKeys(Object o) {
        // Do your reporting stuff
        internal.sendKeys(o);
    }

    // You have to implement proxy methods for other methods you use
}
```

Finally, you should take a look at the [visitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) pattern, it may help you a lot in the future.